# Best approach to authenticate client-certificate

Tags: node.js, express

What is the best approach to validate the client certificate supplied by the user?

i am using express.js and validating certificates using client-certificate-auth.

at the moment i am checking the certificate fingerprint, something like this:

```
 var checkAuth = function (cert) {
     if (cert.fingerprint === 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX') {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 };
```

is this the best approach? or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.